# Python Regexp do not capture www. or .com inside xyz word in text data

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

View this **[Demo RegExp](http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/5)**

I do not want to capture "xyz" word inside between www. or .com

View Screen
[image]

Comment: did you want to match `xyz` in `xyz.com`?

Comment: no i don't want to match xyz inside xyz.com or http: //www.xyz.com

Comment: minus vote explain reason why?

Comment: I think because the question is not clear

Comment: question is not clearn what you means you are not aware regexp, before you give down vote make sure you are right. and you are not clear then leave you opinion. here so many other are understand very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a negative look-behind and looakhead before and after to `xyz`.

```
(?<!www\.)[Xx]yz(?!\.com)(?=[^<>]*<)(?!(<(?:a|span)>(?:.|\n))*</(?:span|a)>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/6)

Comment: I did not downvote and only answered because I was preparing it and did not notice you had already given yours ... But you answered first and yours is more related to question than mine.

Comment: Hey @AvinashRaj i thing your regexp is may be help me. with in 2 day i  inform you and accept your answer. but now i give you up. and thanks alot :)